# Dúvida sobre classes e atributos em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com a uma dúvida sobre classes, atributos e objetos em Python.

Por exemplo usando a classe abaixo:

```
class Car:
     drivers = ['João', 'José']
     def allowed_drivers(self):
             print('The list of allowed drivers: {}.'.format(self.drivers))
```

Faço uma instância `car1` e uma outra instância `car2`:

```
car1 = Car()
car2 = Car()
```

Em seguida adiciono mais um item no atributo `drivers`:

```
car1.drivers.append('Francisco')
```

Quando imprimo o atributo `drivers` do outro objeto `car2`:

```
car2.allowed_drivers()
```

O resultado que obtenho é `'The list of allowed drivers: ['João', 'José', 'Francisco'].'`

O resultado não deveria ser `'The list of allowed drivers: ['João', 'José'].'` neste caso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na resposta da pergunta duplicada você diz que: "Se alterarmos o valor do atributo de um objeto, do outro será alterado também, pois o atributo é da classe.", mas neste pequeno exemplo https://repl.it/@tkrempser/teste1, não é o que acontece.

Comment: Sim e isso me mostrou que minha resposta está incompleta lá. Com lista isso acontece porque é um tipo **mutável**. Você não faz outra atribuição, você apenas modifica o objeto. Quando é inteiro, como mostrou no exemplo, é um tipo **imutável** e você faz **outra atribuição** para alterá-la, com isso a atribuição é feita apenas no atributo de instância.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Mutável você quer dizer que o atributo armazena somente um ponteiro para o endereço da memória no caso da lista e no caso de um número inteiro, temos de fato um número armazenado no atributo (imutável)?

Comment: Thiago, desculpa, estava editando lá. Veja se as novas informações te ajudam. Mas não, não tem a ver com ponteiros (em Python não há ponteiros), mas sim em apenas modificar o valor sem fazer uma nova atribuição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desse modo drivers é uma propriedade estática, ela não pertence a uma instancia em especifico, mas a classe em si.

Para declarar uma propriedade que pertence a uma instancia você declara a propriedade no construtor da classe **init** e utilizando a palavra-chave self:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
      self.drivers = ['João', 'José']

    def allowed_drivers(self):
        print(f'The list of allowed drivers: {self.drivers}')

car1 = Car()
car2 = Car()

car1.drivers.append('Francisco')

car1.allowed_drivers()
car2.allowed_drivers()
```